# Factory Pattern: createABC vs getType(ABC)

Tags: oop, factory, factory-pattern

I am trying to write code that filters a list of objects based on certain properties they have. There are many ways to filter these objects, so I can have multiple filters. I am not sure if this matters for this question, but these filter classes have different constructors.

To control the creation of these filters, I have read about the factory pattern, and decided to try it out. There seems to be two implementations that are widely used:

1. Using a `getType` method, which uses e.g. switch statements on the type to determine which object is built.
2. Creating individual methods for all possible objects that can be created e.g. `createFilterA`, `createFilterB`.

As I see it, the advantages of method (2) are:

- It provides very good visibility of what filters can be made, as
  my IDE immediately tells me the methods available on the factory.
  While method (1) does not make the types of filters that can be made
  known to the user.
- The different methods can tell me what are the arguments needed to construct the different filters.

The advantages of method (1) are:

- We have a way to map a string to a particular type of filter, so users of the API do not have to mess with different classes.

I am wondering if I am missing out on any disadvantages/advantages regarding each of these two implementations? I am currently leaning towards a hybrid, i.e. having both the `getType` and `createFilterX` methods, where the `getType` method switches and calls the individual `createFilterA`, `createFilterB` methods.